# Ubuntu Studio 20.10: Audio Drivers not playing well together ft. Alsa, Jack, and Pulseaudio

Tags: pulseaudio, headphones, ubuntu-studio, jack, 20.10

I've done a lot of searches and read a lot of man pages before coming here but I must not be asking the right questions in my searches and evidently have a lot to learn about these audio controls.
My question is, how do I route audio to my headphones? When I searched for this issue online I found a lot of situations where people were able to fix it with something simple using:

`alsactrl`
`jack_control`

or something similar. All of which did nothing to help my situation.

I don't really need to route audio in such a complex way at this point. I understand it helps with music production by decreasing the latency but another solution would be to remove Jack altogether. However, when I removed Pulse the first time I had to reinstall it just to configure audio at all since apparently the pulseaudio package contains Studio Settings where I can configure bridges and such. I'm scared of having to do a fresh install again though so now I'm here.

Upon checking the Jack audio website, I see it's not recommended that you use Pulse and Jack together. Well, Ubuntu Studio 20.10 ships with them both installed. I'm on my second fresh install, this time on my ssd because it seemed more important than Windows.

I should note, this is my first post and I'm a full-time BioE student so I apologize if I've either neglected to honor etiquette or if I didn't spend enough time searching this. **Time is sacred and headphones are very useful for these classroom Zoom meetings.**

Comment: Update: Even when I'm only using Alsa, I'm only getting speakers to send output. When trying, "alsactl -d monitor" I can  plug/unplug my headphones and they are detected. They also appear in alsa_mixer. I just can't seem to route the audio through them. I've heard it has to do with the "auto mute" feature in other versions of Ubuntu Studio with Jack audio but this is happening with my jack server turned off.

Comment: I don't have any problems using pulseaudio and jack together.  But you don't need to use them together, if jack is not started, you're using pulsaudio connected to alsa. If you start jack, pulseaudio will be routed through jack and jack is connected to alsa. Open `Studio Controls` to check if jack is running or not. If jack is running, stop jack. When jack is not running, you use pulseaudio directly connected with alsa. If you cannot switch to your headphones under this circumstances, it's a problem with pulseaudio.